# How to pass a string from activity to ListActivity in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to pass a String from Activity to ListActivity in Android. When I use normal Activty to Activity String pass method it gives `NullPointerException`. Here is what I tried to do.

Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CheckAvailability.this , ListAtmActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("key", b_name);
startActivity(intent);
```

And I tried to get this from my ListActivity as this.

```
String brName=getIntent().getExtras().getString("key");
```

This working fine for Activity. But It gives `NUllPointerException` when it use in ListActivity.

Please help me.

Comment: i can not see any error in your code it should work clean the project and run again.

Comment: you need to access String brName=getIntent().getExtras().getString("key"); this inside your onCreate().

Comment: Have you tried like this - `String brName=getIntent().getStringExtra("key");` as per **user:Marcin S.**

Comment: @Dasaya if any answer is helping you then accept it so it will help others also.

Answer (score 4):

try using Bundle, that will sort out your problem

```
Bundle d=new Bundle();
d.putString("KEY",Your_String); 
intent.putExtras(d);
startActivity(intent);
```

and now in the ListActivity

```
String Your_String_Variable = getIntent().getStringExtra("KEY");
```

Answer (score 2):

May be your variable b_name is null, To avoid `NUllPointerException` you can declare this variable like as

```
String b_name="";
```

If you variable is null then it will give `NUllPointerException`

Answer (score 1):

Please Use below Code For Get Value from Intent in ListActivity, it will solve your problen.

```
Bundle bdl=getIntent().getExtras();
String mKey=bdl.getString("KEY");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine. As an alternative you could also use:

```
String brName=getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
```